# if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") is not working

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, phpmyadmin

This is a my accounts page the user sees once they have logged in, it displays the user details from the database at the top.

I have added the function to change the password but it isn't working.

I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks the 'submit' button the new password replaces the old password in the database, however the if statement isn't working

When I click the submit button it just refreshes the page because of my `else`.

```
ob_start();

$query ="SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Email='". $_SESSION['Email'] ."'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);


if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $DFirstName = $row ['FirstName'];
    $DLastName = $row ['LastName'];
    $DEmail = $row['Email'];
    $DPassword = $row ['Password'];
    $DGender = $row ['Gender'];
    $DAge = $row ['Age'];

    echo'Welcome: ' .$DFirstName. ' ' .$DLastName. '<br/>';
    echo'Email: ' .$DEmail. '<br/>';
    echo'Gender: ' .$DGender. '<br/>';
    echo'Age: ' .$DAge;

}else{

    echo'error';

}



?>

<h1>Change your password</h1>
<form method="post">
    Old Password <input type="password" name"password" value=''/></br>
    New Password <input type="password" name"newpassword" value=''/></br>
    <input type="submit" name"submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if ($_POST['password'] == $_SESSION['password']){
            $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
            $username = $_SESSION['Email'];
            $query = "UPDATE Customers
                        SET Password = '$newpassword'
                        WHERE Email = '$username'";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            //so that the user has to log back in once password has been changed
            session_destroy();
            header('location:login.php');
        } else {echo 'error1';}
    }else {echo 'error2';}
ob_flush();
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Can you show an error, explain what you expected to see but didn't, etc?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks the submit button the new password replaces the old password in the database however the if statement isnt working

when i click the submit button it just refreshes the page because of my else

Comment: why not just use if($_POST['submit']) ?

Comment: Because of what "else"? Have you really tested whether it goes into the `if` or not? If so, how? If your only indication is that you're not being redirected to login.php afterwards: that's because you're outputting a bunch of stuff before your header.

Comment: Not all browsers send the value of a submit field if you submit the form without using the button (for example by hitting "enter" in a text field). Checking if a submit is set is unreliable.

Comment: This code has SQL injection vulnerabilities, and stores passwords in plain text, which is strongly discouraged (it worsens your users' security problems if your database were to be stolen, which with this code it will). Passwords should be hashed using a suitably strong algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

You have typos in your HTML code:

```
name"password"
name"newpassword"
name"submit"
```

You leaved the `=` sign. Change to this:

```
name="password"
name="newpassword"
name="submit"
```